# How to pass the model object in jquery datatable ajax call

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I am having a class as follows

```
public class ReportSearch
{
    public DateTime? StartDt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDt { get; set; }
    public string VesselName { get; set; }
}
```

where I am trying to pass it to dataTable ajax call as follows

```
var search = {}
search.StartDt = '2022-01-01';
search.EndDt= '2022-02-01';
search.VesselName = 'test';
var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "orderCellsTop": true,
        "fixedHeader": true,
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side
        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Home/LoadData",
            "type": "POST",
            data: '{search: ' + JSON.stringify(search) + '}',
            "datatype": "json"
        },
```

I am having controller as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadData(ReportSearch search)
{
   //but when I debugged it is showing null values instead of the passing values
}
```

How to pass the model correctly instead of individual columns